# SQL поиск максимального в диапазоне

Tags: sql, access

Как сделать правильно такое условие: в какой стране абсолютный прирост за период 2000-2005 был максимальным. Я пробовал такое сделать то не получается. Можете сказать как такое можно сделать?

```
SELECT Max(main_table.value) AS [Max-value], main_table.country, years.year
FROM years 
INNER JOIN main_table ON years.Код = main_table.year
GROUP BY main_table.country, years.year
HAVING (((years.year)>1999 And (years.year)<2006));
```

Переделаный:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
   SELECT MAX(t.value), t.country
   FROM years y
   INNER JOIN main_table as t ON y.Код = t.year
   WHERE y.year>=2000 And y.year<=2005
   GROUP BY t.country
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заверните запрос с группировкой в запрос с сортировкой и лимитом.

Также вероятно имеется в виду совокупный прирост за эти годы. Т.е. SUM и без группировки по годам.

Что-то вроде:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT SUM(t.value) value, t.country
  FROM years y
  INNER JOIN main_table as t ON y.Код = t.year
  WHERE y.year>=2000 And y.year<=2005
  GROUP BY t.country
) grouped 
ORDER BY value desc 
LIMIT 1
```

*Запрос абстрактный, ваша СУБД может иметь другой синтаксис лимитов.
Например `SELECT FIRST 1 ...` или `SELECT TOP 1 ...`*

Comment: 2000-2005 был максимальным

Comment: Разве вопрос не `в какой стране`?

Comment: Поиск максимального достигается сортировкой в убывающем порядке и получение верхней строки результата.

Comment: Я знаю про другой синтаксис, но у меня была проблема с самим запросом который отделял данные

Comment: Я рад, что помог вам решить проблему. [Задавайте ещё!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)